# How can I host an FTP server in Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: ftp, azure

Hoping someone has implemented this before and has a How-to for me, but I have googled for days and come up empty so far.

What I would like to do is implement a simple FTP server within Azure Service Fabric. The server is based on [Fubar's FTP Server](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/FtpServer) and works perfectly outside Service Fabric. I assume the issue I'm having is due to something network-related, i.e. either I'm not opening the right endpoints or something in the Service Fabric config is blocking some aspect of the communication. The FTP server is backed by Azure Blob Storage, but that doesn't seem to make a difference as it's working fine outside Service Fabric.

I have tested the FTP implementation with Filezilla and with the command line ftp client in Windows. Neither can log in, but both manage the initial connection. The log from Filezilla looks like this:

```
Status: Resolving address of localhost
Status: Connecting to [::1]:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server", trying next address.
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 FTP Server Ready
Command:    AUTH TLS
Error:  Connection closed by server
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

So it fails to connect with IPv6, which I'd expect, then tries again with IPv4 and initially succeeds, but then at some point after the AUTH TLS command it gives up. I have ruled out AUTH TLS being the issue by explicitly turning it off in the client, and I get the same behaviour except with no mention of the AUTH TLS command (obviously) and with USER anonymous as the command instead.

I'm hoping this is something simple that I'm not aware of that needs to be addressed when running in Service Fabric.